# Remover última vírgula de um array

Tags: php, array, string, algoritmo

Neste código abaixo tenho um *array* que me retorna uma vírgula no final. Exemplo: **'98602','98603','98604',**

Como posso remover esta vírgula?

```
 if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
 foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    
    $regra = "'{$id}',";
    echo $regra;       
 }}
```

Comment: Não é o array que retorna a vírgula no final, meu amigo. E sim  a string que você está usando

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depois do foreach use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) para remover o último caracter:

Se último parâmetro(lenght) for negativo ele vai remover os caractres no final da string.
Não esqueça de iniciar `$regra` senão seu valor sera sempre 'resetado' a cada volta do for.

```
 if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $regra = '';
    foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
      $id = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

      $regra .= "'{$id}',";

    }
    $regra = substr($regra, 0, -1);
    echo $regra;
 }
```

Outra maneira de formatar essa string de uma só vez é combinar a primeira e a última aspa simples entre chamada de implode:

```
$arr = array('98602','98603','98604'); // equivalente o $_POST
$novo = "'". implode("','", $arr) ."'";
echo 'implode '. $novo;
```

Saida:

```
'98602','98603','98604'
```

Comment: Eu só não tinha usado implode por causa do escape que ele faz na string antes, mas é uma alternativa interessante pra casos mais simples do que o da questão.

Comment: @Bacco, estou testando com array_map para chamar o `mysql_real_escape_string `

Answer (score 10):

Tem várias formas, inclusive dá para fazer um algoritmo que ela não seja inserida. Acho que o mais fácil seria o [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/RTRIM):

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $regra = "'{$id}',";
        echo $regra;       
    }
    rtrim($regra, ',');
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/RemoveFinalChar.php).

Answer (score 8):

Baseado no que o @Maniero mencionou, uma maneira é não inserir a vírgula, ao invés de removê-la. Notar que o código fica mais extenso do que com `rtrim`:

```
$regra = '';
$separador = '';
if ( isset( $_POST['checkbox'] ) ) {
   foreach ( $_POST['checkbox'] as $value ) {
      $regra .= $separador."'".mysql_real_escape_string( $value )."'";
      $separador = ',';
   }
}
echo $regra;
```

Aproveitei para dar uma pequena otimizada tirando o `echo` da lógica principal e removendo o `$key =>` e o `$id` que não são necessários neste caso.

Answer (score 8):

Podes mapear essa array e depois juntar os elementos da array com virgulas no meio:

```
$func = function($value) {
     $id = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
     return "'{$id}'";
};

$ids = array_map($func, $_POST['checkbox']);
echo implode(",", $ids);
```

Tens outras respostas corretas, esta é uma outra abordagem que prefiro.
O `if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))` ainda é necessário, essa parte podes manter.

Comment: Me desculpa, não vi que você tinha respondido isso já! +1

Answer (score -3):

Uma outra forma de resolver também seria

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  $regra = "";
  foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

    $regra .= ($regra != "" ? "," : "") . "'{$id}'";
  }
 }
```

Comment: Olá. A segunda metade da resposta foi removida pois aqui isso é considerado spam. Se quiser, fique à vontade para promover sua empresa ou produto [no seu próprio perfil de usuário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22712/hostech-brasil). Obrigado.