# Quero imprimir os valores separados por virgulas mas no final fica uma virgula que não quero usar em JAVA

Tags: java, for, brasil

Quero remover a última vírgula; ná saída depois do 30

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        for(int i=1; i<=30; i++){
            System.out.print(i);
            for(int j=0; j<=0; j++)
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
}
```

A saída do programa é:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53333/101. Ou trate como exceção, vá até o penúltimo e depois faça o última fora do laço.

Comment: ótima gambiarra

Comment: Tu não precisas desse `for(int j=0; j<=0; j++)`, essa linha não faz nada para ti nesse contexto...

Comment: `public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     for(int i=1; i<=29; i++){
      System.out.print(i);
      for(int j=0; j<=0; j++)
      System.out.print(",");
     }
     
         System.out.print("30");
 }
}
´

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado
Sim eu já fiz sem a linha também, funciona da mesma forma

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado mas o problema a ser tratado não era esse, tanto que ele persistia no outro modelo também, mas o jeito como o Maniero disse funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção é colocar uma condição de teste para saber se deve ou não imprimir a última virgula.
No caso foi utilizado um [operador condicional ternário](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) dentro de um método [System.out.printf()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) que imprima uma string formatada.

O operador condicional ternário que verifica se `i` é o ultimo elemento a ser impresso:

- caso não imprime um caractere virgula(caractere ASCII 44)
- caso sim não imprima caractere algum(caractere ASCII 00)

A [string de formato](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

- `%d` resulta num um número inteiro decimal.
- `%c` resulta num caractere Unicode.

```java
public class Main {
   static final int MAX_NUM = 30;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++){
          System.out.printf("%d%c",i, i==MAX_NUM ? 00: 44);
      }
  }
}
```

Que resulta:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/B6YukJ)</sup>